# Need culturally sensitive alternatives to standard videography terminology such as "shoot," "shooting," and "shot."

Tags: video, video-recording, production, shooting, terminology

The idea of "shooting" makes some people uncomfortable, so we're trying to change our terminology for a particular client (big 6-month project). We need to come up with appropriate alternatives to use for terms in all of our written plans and processes for this project. And though there are many terms we can use, I'm wondering if there is a new standard or commonly used alternatives. We need alternatives for "shoot," "shooting," and "shot."

Answer (score 2):

What about:

- film, filming, filmed
- record, recording, recorded